# glFinish and FPS

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, frame-rate

I am using a simple opengl mediaplayer android application. In onDrawFrame function, there is glFinish function call. If I comment that call, in Adreno Profiler, my FPS drops down after some time of playback (after about 20 mins). If it is not commented, FPS will not drop down. Why is it so.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact it happens after some time delay means it's probably environmental (all things being equal). I assume it's probably overheating and thermal throttling kicks in; with the `glFinish` still in place the pipeline is draining which gives the GPU a chance to cool down.

Comment: @ Isogen74 : Thankyou for your answer. Adding glFinish did solve my issue. Now, I have a different app in which shaders are more busy. Adding glFinish didnt solve the issue. FPS dropped after 20 mins. However adding some glGetError checks made some progress. FPS didnt drop for 1 hour and then  again it dropped. Is there any solution for this environmental issue.?

Comment: Not really - it's a thermal limiter in the phone to stop the chip damaging itself. Getting heat out of a sealed plastic box with no fan is hard. 

In general you just need to optimize your application so it doesn't need to run the GPU so fast, giving it time to cool, or opportunity for a lower operating voltage.